# http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/ with XAMMP error

Tags: javascript, php, xampp, cart

I know this problem is very concrete but I'm really lost right now I don't know what I should do (if it's so just delete this post).

I'm trying to use http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/ in my local server but it crashes right away (I'm using xammp and jcart unmodified as you can download from their respective servers).
I've tried to upload to my university server and it works so I know the problem is with xammp but I can't locate it.

Not the right admin rights? too much updated version of php?...
Errors:
[image]

If I can't find it I'll just work with the server of my university directly but I know this is a thing I shouldn't do.

Comment: is there any problem with your database?

Comment: Actually this version of jcart doesn't use the database so the problem shouldn't be there

Comment: Do you have any Apache error logs?

Comment: No not one, its fresh installed

Comment: Have you read this : http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/help/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=853

Comment: Mmm there it says that he just changed host, I think I'm just going work in another server, thanks for all the trouble!!